# How to detect chromecast model in receiver?

Tags: model, device, chromecast, receiver

I only found how to get sdk version using cast api. Is there any way to detect which model of chromecast the receiver is running on? ie. First generation? Second? Ultra?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I created a custom typescript class that we use for reporting. We use this to accurately detect what device a user is using based off what the devices can support. This may not work for Android TV.

```
private supported720PWidth = 1280;
private supported720PHeight = 720;
private supported1080PWidth = 1920;
private supported1080PHeight = 1080;
private supported2160PWidth = 3840;
private supported2160pHeight = 2160;
private mp4 = 'video/mp4';
private codecH264Lvl4Dot1 = 'avc1.640028';
private codecH264Lvl4Dot2 = 'avc1.64002A';
private firstGenLastSupportedOS = '1.36';
private codecH265 = 'hev1.1.6.L150.B0'
private context = CastReceiverContext.getInstance()



//https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#audio_passthrough we use codec because each device has a limitation so makes this as accurate as it can be
public isDeviceUltra(): boolean {
    return this.context.canDisplayType(this.mp4, this.codecH265, this.supported2160PWidth, this.supported2160pHeight, 30);
}

public isDevice3rdGen(): boolean {
    return this.context.canDisplayType(this.mp4, this.codecH264Lvl4Dot2, this.supported1080PWidth, this.supported1080PHeight, 60);
}

public isDevice2ndGen(): boolean {
    return this.context.canDisplayType(this.mp4, this.codecH264Lvl4Dot1, this.supported1080PWidth, this.supported1080PHeight, 30);
}

public isDevice1stGen(): boolean {
    return this.context.canDisplayType(this.mp4, this.codecH264Lvl4Dot1, this.supported1080PWidth, this.supported1080PHeight) && this.isOSLowerThanOrEqual(this.firstGenLastSupportedOS);
}

public isDeviceNestHub(): boolean {
    return this.context.canDisplayType(this.mp4, this.codecH264Lvl4Dot1, this.supported720PWidth, this.supported720PHeight, 60);
}

public isDeviceNestHubMax(): boolean {
    return this.context.canDisplayType(this.mp4, this.codecH264Lvl4Dot1, this.supported720PWidth, this.supported720PHeight, 30);
}

private getDevicesOSVersion(): string {
    let userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toString();
    let userAgentSplit = userAgent.split('/', 8);
    let fullOS = userAgentSplit[userAgentSplit.length - 1];
    return fullOS;
}

private isOSLowerThanOrEqual(expectedOS: string): boolean {
    let os = this.getDevicesOSVersion().split('.', 2);
    let expectedOSArray = expectedOS.split('.', 2);
    if (Number(os[1]) <= Number(expectedOSArray[1])) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shows incorrect value for a Chromecast ultra

Answer (score 1):

No names, but you can guess?

DeviceCapabilities->IS_HDR_SUPPORTED = a newer one

```
castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
castReceiverManager.getDeviceCapabilities()
// gives: is_hdr_supported = false, on first generation
```

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager#.DeviceCapabilities

Comment: While it filters out the first generation, it doesn't differentiate v2 from ulta :(

Comment: Yes thats true. Best would be to make the sender send the model name, because: "HDR video support of the current setup (that is, Chromecast and the TV it is connected to).". 

But this also just gives Chromecast or Chromecast Ultra.

Comment: Then one could most likely differentiate between v1 and v2 by checking bluetooth support.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no API to return the model or version of the cast device it is running on.

Comment: Why is this? How can I identify that I am running on an Ultra for example, so I can start an HEVC stream in 4K? Also for example Sony Android TVs do not play high framerate content like they should.

Comment: I'm also curious to know if there's a reason for this? Is this something Google is trying to prohibit? Is there any other API that can be used to guess the version?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect model name on sender side https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/CastDevice.html#getModelName()
"Chromecast","Chromecast Ultra"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you can provide more details, explanation, and/or example code you will improve your chances of helping the asker and gain [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: That's only for Android